# Webjob to pass parameters and trigger C# solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, webjob

I am completely new to web job. From my reading, I came to know it is something through we can enable trigger to run our script. I have C# code which copies files from ftp server to blob container. It takes few parameters like host, username. I want to create a web job that will pass parameters to the code and trigger the solution as well. Can you please help me with the steps and if possible provide articles relevant to it especially passing of paramters. Detailed steps like creation of dll file of code will be appreciated.

Thanking in advance

Comment: Is there any updates about this thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to pass the few parameters like host, username to the WebJob from your app and copy your file from ftp server to blob? If yes, from my experience, we can pass the parameter as queue message. We can write our message with the customized format. Such as “{hostname, user}”, you could define the format yourself. Then we can use the queue to trigger the WebJob. When we push a message onto a queue, a backend service pulls messages from the queue and does the work. How to write a queue message please refer to [document](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-queues/#insert-a-message-into-a-queue).  Then we can use WebJob SDK (QueueTrigger) to get the queue message and get the parameters that we wanted. How to use WebJob SDK, please refer to the [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk/).

Comment: Thanks Tom. Sorry for the very late reply. It helped a lot

Comment: hi Tom, do you have any idea about the below: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42917856/regarding-run-command-and-using-sdk-from-azure-webjob-logs