# Regarding run_command and using_sdk from Azure webjob logs

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

My webjob is suppose to do some work but we found it is not running. When, we went through the azure logs (Kudu webjob logs), we found that it is running some other file. like **run_command** =  "" has some other .exe file. Also, **using_sdk** is set to false. What do you think might have caused it. How to set right path to it. We are using octopus for deployment.

Comment: do you fix the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> we went through the azure logs (Kudu webjob logs), we found that it is running some other file. like run_command = "" has some other .exe file.

From [this documentation](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs), we could know WebJobs use the specified logic to decide which file is the script to run within the job's directory:

- Per file type we look first for a file named: run.{file type
  extension} (for example run.cmd or run.exe).
- If it doesn't exists for all file types, we'll then look for the
  first file with a supported file type extension.

Please try to rename the file ({jobname}.exe) that you want to run to **run.exe** to check if it runs as expected.